# Where does gravity get's its energy from?

Tags: gravity

So I have read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75222/where-does-gravity-get-its-energy-from) post and I have another question about it. The first answer says that if we lift an object up that is the energy we "give" to gravity and then gravity uses that energy to pull the object back down. But if we launch a rocket and that rocket goes in a stable orbit gravity will keep applying energy to it to pull it back down.

So let's say that the energy that was required to launch the rocket was 1000 Newtons, and that gravity uses a force of .1 Newtons per second to pull it back down. It will then take 10000 seconds to reach the energy that we used to launch it. So after that 10000 seconds where does gravity then get its energy from?