# Is it possible that gravitation is not reconcilable with quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-gravity

And if so would there be any way of proving this?

Comment: No, that is not possible. What is possible is that gravitation is not a fundamental phenomenon but emergent (in a thermodynamics sense) in itself. As such if may not need to be explained with quantum mechanics directly anymore than we need a quantum mechanical theory of surface waves on our oceans. In that case, however, whatever gravity emerges from has to be reconciled with quantum mechanics, which also doesn't mean that "it" has to have a quantum mechanical explanation. Instead "it" could be the explanation for QM itself.

Answer (score -2):

No that is not possible. [Gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity) was originally developed as a theory, by which all thing with **mass** are brought toward one another. Nowadays the theory is the same, but it's said to influence on everything with **energy**.

This change includes the photon which has energy but no mass. This is actually contradiction. As [Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy) is defined with [Joule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_energy) which is $kg\frac{m^2}{s^2}$ and has thus allways mass in it. So you could actually calculate the mass of a photon through it's wave lenght; $E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$ and $E=mc^2$
But this is forbitten by simply stating "photon energy is not related to mass".

Though it obviously shows how our physics has contradictions. 
According to [Galileo's maxim](http://www.conservapedia.com/Galileo's_maxim) "**two truths can never contradict each other**"
we could easily conclude that there Either is mass on photon OR there is no mass at all.

But as this causes our whole physic to collapse; Newton's  $F=ma$ is all over the place. So it's mentally easier to say there is no mass on photon, and to maintain this contradiction, than it is to accept the truth.

It's all just light. And the Mass is as fictitious thing as [Centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) is.

I have paper about this. But giving the link causes a delete/close/down vote lavine, and a dialogue I don't need. So I just say that the effects of Gravity can be completely explained by QED, and thus there actually isn't any gravity.

Some more info here; 
[Where does gravity get its energy from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75222/where-does-gravity-get-its-energy-from/238804#238804)