# Does gravity follow law of conservation of energy?

Tags: gravity, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, mass-energy

Law of conservation of energy states that energy cant be created nor destroyed.I dont understand how it is applicable for a object moving under influence of gravity.If some force has been applied on an object due to the influence gravity making the object gain energy as kinetic or pottential then from where does the energy come from?

How is this gravitational pull produced between matter?

I have a serious doubt in this and sorry if i made a blunder question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does gravity get its energy from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75222/)

Comment: See **Change in potential energy of a system is defined as the negative of work done by internal conservative forces of the system**. I think that it is sufficient enough to answer your question.