# FORCE needs ENERGY, where does GRAVITATION get its ENERGY from to ATTRACT two bodies

Tags: energy, gravity

Force requires energy.
Gravitation is the force of attraction.
So where does gravitation get its energy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy

Comment: ALL CAPS = SHOUTING

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does gravity get its energy from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75222/)

Answer (score 3):

Energy is not required to exert a force.

That I imagine answers the question.

Comment: This is a spectacularly unhelpful answer. Objects move under gravity so the gravitational force does work, and that does require energy. While technically correct your answer helps no-one.

Comment: @JohnRennie I don't understand the objection. Objects do not have to move under gravity (e.g. my table isn't falling into the Earth) so the gravitational force does not have to do work, even though a force is still there.

Comment: The fact that a force can do work does not mean that force requires energy. As it does not imply that a force has to do work in order to exist. The OP premise is false. A body can move in a circular orbit under gravity and there is no work done by gravity. Still, gravity force exists.